# How do I search for a substring and get match indices while allowing mismatches with Python?

Tags: python

I am looking to find a string allowing for up 2 mismatches. I can do this with:

```
import regex
regex.findall("(key_string){s<=2}", "kei_strung has two mismatches")
```

and I get: `['kei_strung']`

What I would like to do is to retrieve the start and end position indices, which I could get using `re.search()`. Unfortunately, I dont know how to allow for 2 mismatches using `re.search()`.

How do you get this outcome?

Comment: I got an empty list `[]`

Comment: Possible typos in question.

Comment: Google "Levenshtein distance".

Comment: @Corralien, well spotted, I wrote it from memory. I used regex

Comment: Was about to say, the `re` package doesn't support extensions like `{s<=2}`.

Comment: @BenY but the `regex` package does.

Comment: The original question (prior to the edit) was phrased with `re`, which doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex.finditer` instead `regex.findall`:

```
for m in regex.finditer("(key_string){s<=2}", "kei_strung has two mismatches"):
    print(f"{m.group()}: [{m.start()}-{m.end()}]")

kei_strung: [0-10]
```